# Filter on Google Sheet with many rows

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently working on a Sheet file that allows to register people. Each person corresponds to a line and it is necessary to assign different data (in relation to each other). To facilitate the input of this information, I have chosen to use drop-down menus.

For example, if you choose a certain value as the first data, I want to see only the values corresponding to this choice appear in the second drop-down menu. So I have a file that holds the records and another where the data to be assigned are written ([file link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wnKBBPaLHdL2p956OZbEDmzuo6OAwTQf9nlKPnaA6t4/edit?usp=sharing)).

To create the link between two drop-down menus, I used the Filter function (in a third column) to display only the data that correspond to the choice made in the first drop-down menu.

Everything works perfectly for the first record. Here is the corresponding macro: "=FILTER(B2:B;A2:A=Sheet!B2)". However, when I go to line 3, it no longer works since I filled in B2 in the formula. I don't see myself duplicating this correspondence on X lines since I don't know how many people I should record.

I'm expect there is an alternative method to solve this, but I can't find it on the internet.

Comment: What about `=FILTER($B$2:B;$A$2:A=Sheet!B2)`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't work because it is in the Sheet tab that rows are added. And your formula always refers to B2 (A=Sheet!B2). If I add more people, it should be B3, then B4, ...
It's this B2 that blocks me and I can't find a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apps Script to create Drop-down Data Validations in column C based on the choice selected in column B.

### Sample Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ss = e.source;
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.range;

  if (activeSheet.getName() == "Sheet" && cell.getColumn() == 2 && cell.getRow() > 1) {
    // Get selected choice 1
    var choice1 = cell.getValue();
    Logger.log(choice1);

    if (choice1 == ""){
      // Remove data validation in the adjacent column (column C)
      cell.offset(0,1).clearDataValidations()
      cell.offset(0,1).setValue("");
    }else{
      // Create a dropdown list
      // Read database
      var dataBase = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase").getRange("A2:B").getValues();
      // Filter data
      var choices = [];
      dataBase.forEach(row => {
        if(row[0]==choice1){
          choices.push(row[1]);
        }
      });
      Logger.log(choices);

      // Create data validation
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
        .requireValueInList(choices, true)
        .setAllowInvalid(false)
        .build();
      // Add data validation to the adjacent column (column C) and reset cell value
      cell.offset(0,1).setValue("");
      cell.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(rule);
    }
    
  }
}
```

### What it does?

- Using [onEdit simple trigger,](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) create a data validation whenever a value
- Check if the modified cell is in "Sheet" tab,in column B (index 2) and modified row is > row 1
- Get the value of the choice1 selected in column B
- Get the values in "DataBase" tab and filter the data. Get the Choice 2 values based on the selected choice1
- Create a new data validation drop-down list based on the filtered data to the adjacent cell (column C). Reset the value to empty cell.
- If the choice selected is empty (cell deleted), Remove the data validation on the adjacent cell and set the value to empty cell

### Output:

[image]